# Bad layout and wrapping on simple Bootstrap page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to create a simple Bootstrap page that has four input fields each with a side button. The four input fields to be in a line horizontally and centered across the screen.

With the code I have written the fields are offset to the right (so not centered) and when the screen is shrunk the wrapping looks awful. My code looks like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>WIA</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <style>
        .wia-color {
            color: #00DDDD;
        }

        .wia-navbar-logo {
            margin-top: -6px;
            max-height: 44px;
            height: 44px;
        }

        .wia-top-section {
            height: 800px;
            background-color: transparent;
        }

        .wia-logo-strapline {
            margin-top: 0px;
            max-height: 123px;
            height: 123px;
        }

        .wia-strapline-text {
            color: white;
            font-size: 40px !important;
            font-family: Open Sans;
            font-weight: 100;
            font-style: normal;
            margin-top: 38px;
        }

        .wia-filter-column {
            width: 280px;
        }

        .wia-filter-row {
            color: white;
            margin-top: 50px;
            font-size: 18px;
            font-weight: 400;
        }

        .wia-filter-container {
            width: 250px;
            white-space: nowrap;
            float:left;
        }
        .wia-filter-label {
            color: white;
            font-size: 18px;
            font-weight: 200;
            float: left;
            padding-left: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 4px;
        }

        .wia-filter-value {
            value: 'xxx';
            width: 200px;
            height: 30px;
            background-color: #141414;
            border-style: solid;
            border-left-width: 3px;
            border-left-color: #00DDDD;
            border-top: none;
            border-bottom: none;
            border-right: none;
            color: white;
            font-size: 18px;
            font-weight: 200;
            padding-left: 4px;
        }

        .wia-filter-button {
            width: 30px;
            height: 30px;
            background-color: #222626;
            color: #00DDDD;
            border: none;
            vertical-align: top;
            margin-left: -5px;
            font-weight:100;
        }

        /* Remove the navbar's default margin-bottom and rounded borders */
        .navbar {
            margin-bottom: 0;
            border-radius: 0;
        }

        .navbar-inverse {
            background-color: #222626;
            height: 64px;
            max-height: 64px;
            min-height: 64px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Donate</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="jumbotron wia-top-section">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row wia-filter-row">
            <div class="col-sm-2">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 wia-filter-column">
                <div class="wia-filter-label">
                    What
                </div>
                <br/>
                <div class="wia-filter-container">
                    <input class="wia-filter-value" type="text" placeholder="One">
                    <button class="wia-filter-button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 wia-filter-label wia-filter-column">
                <div class="wia-filter-label">
                    Where
                </div>
                <br/>
                <div class="wia-filter-container">
                    <input class="wia-filter-value" type="text" placeholder="Two">
                    <button class="wia-filter-button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 wia-filter-label wia-filter-column">
                <div class="wia-filter-label">
                    When
                </div>
                <br/>
                <div class="wia-filter-container">
                    <input class="wia-filter-value" type="text" placeholder="Three">
                    <button class="wia-filter-button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 wia-filter-label wia-filter-column">
                <div class="wia-filter-label">
                    Who
                </div>
                <br/>
                <div class="wia-filter-container">
                    <input class="wia-filter-value" type="text" placeholder="Four">
                    <button class="wia-filter-button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span></button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container wia-filter-label text-center">
        SOME MORE STUFF
    </div>
</div>


<!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have created a plunker here:

https://plnkr.co/edit/V0KVM1J2xX1FRAiFYW16?p=preview

Comment: You are not using bootstrap grid properly. Why are you giving your own widths to the grids?

Comment: I tried without giving widths at first but the layout was even worse.

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 2):

The thing is that column elements in bootstrap are naturally floated, thus will always try to adjust to one side (in this case left).

You can try to set the CSS as something like:

```
.wia-filter-row {
 text-align:center;
}
.wia-filter-row .col-sm-2{
 float:none;
 display: inline-block;
}
```

So you can have the columns with the proper width and displayed in one line.
By the way you don't need the empty divs to force the spacing. You can use the col-sm-offset-2.

Comment: Thanks Marina, I tried that but I still get the same problems. Thanks though for the col-sm-offest-2 tip I had completely forgotten about offsets!

Answer (score 1):

This is what i would do. Use bootstrap grid for the layout and add my own class to change the colors. 
This should help you understand and create better grids.

In the code, i have used everything bootstrap has to offer along with my custom class on 2nd button so that you can understand.

Check the code here : http://codepen.io/hunzaboy/pen/RogvQj

```
<div class="container" style="margin-top: 30px;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="..." placeholder="One">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="caret"></span></button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /btn-group -->
      </div>
      <!-- /input-group -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-custom" aria-label="..." placeholder="Button with class">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-custom dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="caret"></span></button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /btn-group -->
      </div>
      <!-- /input-group -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="..." placeholder="One">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="caret"></span></button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /btn-group -->
      </div>
      <!-- /input-group -->
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="..." placeholder="One">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><span class="caret"></span></button>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /btn-group -->
      </div>
      <!-- /input-group -->
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- /.row -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that. I am having difficulty moving your code over to mine with my button style and my labels above the input fields. The input fields are over to the left of the screen rather than centered.

Comment: Please check official bootstrap website for layouts and form elements.  It will help you alot.

Comment: Yes indeed. The Bootstrap documentation is very good. I have spent many hours studying it and having failed to come to an understanding of why my code wasn't working I sought help here.

Comment: You only have to include bootstrap css file,  and try all the component codes given in the bootstrap documentation.  Just copy and paste and all will work.  I will suggest to watch bootstrap tutorials on YouTube.  It will help.

Comment: Yup done that too! Please understand that I am posting here because I am unable to sort out the problems with the code despite spending many hours pouring over the Bootstrap docs. Clearly something I am doing to the Bootstrap template I started with is screwing things up. Hopefully someone will be able to help.